# Can I replace a string inside of a column named "key" in Mysql using MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I need to replace a few thousands unique strings in a few milion entries. Doing it by hand is not an option.

How do I replace a string inside of a column named "key" in Mysql using MySQL workbench? Is it impossible unless I rename the column name, just to do the operation? Are there any work arounds?

**First line works the second is broken:**

```
UPDATE DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME SET module = replace(module, 'ORIGINAL_STRING', 'REPLACED_STRING');
UPDATE DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME SET key = replace (key, 'ORIGINAL_STRING', 'REPLACED_STRING');
```

**Error Code**

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = replace (key 'ORIGINAL_STRING', 'REPLACED_STRING')'

Comment: Key is a key word for mysql, put ` around the word like \`key\` let you get what you want

Comment: SET `key` = replace (`key` 'ORIGINAL_STRING', 'REPLACED_STRING'); / wont work.

Comment: the same error?

Comment: You are missing a comma after \`key\`. It should be `SET \`key\` = REPLACE(\`key\`, 'ORIGINAL_STRING', 'REPLACED_STRING');`

Comment: @kmoser Thanks for noticing that comma bit! That fixed the "second" issue.

Comment: @ElapsedSoul please add it as an answer I'll gladly upvote. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key is a key word for mysql.

You need to surround by ` the word like :

`key`

It will let you achieve what you want.